# How do I filter a minimum and maximum salary for each seperate department?

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

I am referencing a set of tables in which a department contains multiple employees, each of whom has a `salary`.

The `department_id`, `employee_id`, and `salary` are all part of the `EMPLOYEES` table. I would like to determine the minimum and maximum salaries in each department.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name||' '||last_name AS full_name, SALARY
       DECODE(department_id, 50, (min(salary)||' '||max(salary)),
                             60, (min(salary)||' '||max(salary)),
                             80, (min(salary)||' '||max(salary)),
                             90, (min(salary)||' '||max(salary)),
              employee_id)
       SALARY_RANGE
FROM   EMPLOYEES;
```

Thoughts on how to complete this query? Thanks

Comment: I am using oracle. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the minimum and maximum salaries in each department, why not just do:

```
select department_id, min(salary)||' '||max(salary) as Salary_Range
from Employees
group by department_id;
```

You can limit this to particular departments using `where`:

```
select department_id, min(salary)||' '||max(salary) as Salary_Range
from Employees
where department_id in (50, 60, 80, 90)
group by department_id;
```

Comment: This works well. Is there a single line that could be added to limit the results to certain department ids?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a group by statement on Department and the min and max salary in your selection.  This would give you the min and max per department.  You could then Join in additional data points that you would want in your final projection.

example:

```
SELECT min(salary), max(salary)
FROM Salary
GROUP BY Department
```